# export unity3d scene as ios app with slide out sidebar menu

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I work on unity3d scene, I want to export the unity project as iOS app.
the exported unity app will run as fullscreen app without any control or menu buttons. 
How can I add a slideout sidebar menu to the exported app?

Comment: Can you explain more? What exactly you need?

Comment: @NeerajKumar, I have unity3d project, I want to export it as ios app.
but I want to add slideout sidebar menu to the exported appp to get the desired app.

Comment: Your question is too broad, there can be many ways to achieve this. If you have tried something and it is not working then you can post your script file here, that way I can help you better. Anyways if you have not tried anything or don't know where to start, I will suggest you to implement gesture detection system.  There you can define some pattern of gestures to show  slideout sidebar menu.

Comment: Hi. Do you have any lead on this. Am trying to do the same with no luck